# How can you export an IAR configuration? Specifically colors and fonts

Tags: ide, embedded, iar

I would like to synchronize colors and fonts between two different instances of IAR's IDE. I know there is no way to export using the IDE itself, but are there configuration files that can be copied to achieve the same result? 
[image]

Comment: Please show some code that you attempted - that will make it easier for others to provide a solution.

Comment: This is about exporting IDE preferences, it doesn't have anything to do with any particular code. I added a screenshot of the preferences that I'm trying to export.

Comment: @Roy - It will probably be regarded as off-topic in SO since even though it is about  development software it is not really about using that software for development.  I suggest you make a change to the settings then look in the installation folder to see which file or files get updated (by their timestamp).  You may find the files are in a human readable format such as XML or INI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the file that contains the configuration in XML format:

C:\users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\IAR Embedded Workbench\IarIde.xml

This is the relevant section:

```
<TextEditor>
    <Font0>_ 0 400 0 16777215 0</Font0>
    <Font1>_ 0 700 0 16711935 0</Font1>
    <Font2>_ 0 400 0 32896 0</Font2>
    <Font3>_ 0 400 0 16776960 0</Font3>
    <Font4>_ 0 400 0 255 0</Font4>
    <Font5>_ 0 400 0 38400 0</Font5>
    <Font6>_ 0 400 0 0 0</Font6>
    <Font7>_ 0 400 0 0 0</Font7>
    <Font8>_ 0 400 0 0 0</Font8>
    <Font9>_ 0 400 255 65280 0</Font9>
    <Font10>_ 0 400 255 65280 0</Font10>
    <Font11>_ 0 400 255 16776960 0</Font11>
    <Font12>_ 0 400 255 16776960 0</Font12>
    <Font13>_ 0 700 0 0 1</Font13>
    <Font14>_ 0 400 255 10485760 0</Font14>
    <FontsEx>_ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1776411 0</FontsEx>
    <Fonts>_ -13 400 3 2 1 49 "Consolas" 15</Fonts>
    <IndentSize>_ 2</IndentSize>
    <TabSize>_ 2</TabSize>
    <AutoIndent>_ 1</AutoIndent>
    <BraceIndent>_ 0</BraceIndent>
    <BodyIndent>_ 2</BodyIndent>
    <LabelIndent>_ 0</LabelIndent>
    <RealTabs>_ 0</RealTabs>
    <SyntaxHLight>_ 1</SyntaxHLight>
    <ShowBookmarks>_ 1</ShowBookmarks>
    <ShowLineNumbers>_ 0</ShowLineNumbers>
    <ShowFoldsMargin>_ 1</ShowFoldsMargin>
    <ScanForChangedFiles>_ 1</ScanForChangedFiles>
    <VirtualSpace>_ 0</VirtualSpace>
    <CmdLineApp>_ ""</CmdLineApp>
    <CmdLineArgs>_ ""</CmdLineArgs>
    <DdeApp>_ ""</DdeApp>
    <DdeServiceName>_ ""</DdeServiceName>
    <FindFlags>_ 6</FindFlags>
    <LineBreakUsage>_ 0</LineBreakUsage>
    <TrimTrailingBlanks>_ 0</TrimTrailingBlanks>
    <UseUserKeyWordFile>_ 0</UseUserKeyWordFile>
    <UserKeyWordFile>_ ""</UserKeyWordFile>
    <UseCodeTemplates>_ 1</UseCodeTemplates>
    <CodeTemplateFile>_ "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\IAR Embedded Workbench\CodeTemplates.ENU.txt"</CodeTemplateFile>
    <ShowRightMargin>_ 1</ShowRightMargin>
    <UsePrinterMargin>_ 0</UsePrinterMargin>
    <RightMarginPos>_ 80</RightMarginPos>
    <AutoCompletion>_ 1</AutoCompletion>
    <AutoDetectEncoding>_ 1</AutoDetectEncoding>
    <DefaultEncoding>_ "System"</DefaultEncoding>
    <ShowLineBreaks>_ 0</ShowLineBreaks>
    <ShowSourceBrowserToolTips>_ 1</ShowSourceBrowserToolTips>
    <ShowVisibleWhitespace>_ 0</ShowVisibleWhitespace>
    <SyntaxHighlightRubyFiles>_ 1</SyntaxHighlightRubyFiles>
    <DdeCmdStr>_ 0</DdeCmdStr>
</TextEditor>
```

Comment: But this file is reset every time we open IAR. The data in it can't be persisted